# Automatically answering an interactive prompt with "yes"

Tags: apt, upgrade, keyboard, prompt

Some daemons ask if they shall be restarted, when they've got an update. I get asked whether I want to restart them or not. It opens a purple colored window, where I am supposed to navigate to `yes`or `no` with my keyboard and then hit "Enter".
I am looking for a way to automatically say "yes" in those interactive prompts, so it can be used in scripts. Only using the `-y` flag, does not work. Neither works `yes | apt upgrade`. I am still forced to navigate with my keyboard.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` environment variable set to skip all interactive dialog boxes with the default response:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y upgrade
```

See also [Automatically answer 'Yes' when using apt-get install](https://superuser.com/a/939651/418736) on Super User.